# changing basis in linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^5$ and $S: \Bbb{R}^5 \to \Bbb{R}^3$ be a linear transformation defined by 
$$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x
\\y   
\end{bmatrix}\right)
= 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
y
\\x  
\\y  
\\x+y  
\\x-y
\end{bmatrix}\right)$$ and $$S\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x_1
\\x_2  
\\x_3  
\\x_4  
\\x_5  
\end{bmatrix}\right)
= 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
2x_1-x_3+x_5
\\x_2+x_4
\\x_1
\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

Let $E$ be the standard basis of $\Bbb R^5$. Let $B$ and $D$ be the bases of $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$, respectively where  $B_1 = \{v_1,v_2\}$ and $D = \{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ with
$$v_1 = 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1  
\\-2
\end{bmatrix}\right), v_2 = 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
-3  
\\4
\end{bmatrix}\right), w_1 = 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1
\\0
\\1 
\end{bmatrix}\right)$$ $$ w_2 = 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
-1
\\1 
\\1  
\end{bmatrix}\right), w_3 = 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
0
\\0 
\\1 
\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

Looking for some help with the following:

1) $M_{E\leftarrow B}(T)$
2) $M_{D\leftarrow E}(S)$
3) $M_{D\leftarrow B}(ST)$

My thinking so far:

1) $M_{E\leftarrow B}(T)$ My logic here is to just take $T$ and dot it with $v_1,v_2$ and then put it in the basis of E with E being $$ E= 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0  
\\0&1&0&0&0  
\\0&0&1&0&0  
\\0&0&0&1&0  
\\0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}\right)$$ however I do not think the dimensions of $T$ and $v_1$ and $v_2$ can be dotted together, So my logic was the same for number 2 also.

Comment: There seems to be a surplus of parentheses here...

Comment: @user259242 yes I am afraid if I take them out I will mess up the format

Comment: do you know how to answer my questions?

Answer (score 1):

Ok start by applying the change of basis (I assume you don't know how to do that, hence why you used dot product) So for 1) write E as a linear combination of B. Then apply the transformation.

Comment: @TheProoflsTrivial once i do that do i carry on with what i said in my question?

Comment: No. After that it is complete...

Comment: How do I express B as a linear combination of E? I just need some guidance in the first one so I can complete the rest

Comment: For example v1 = (1)e1+(-2)e2. Once you have all of your vectors in B rewritten, apply the transformation.

Comment: Sorry, I got a little confused with your notation, I guess you should write E as linear combinations of B instead. My apologies, however, the concept is the same.